# Running bash script in rtorrent does not output to file

Tags: bash, rtorrent

I have rtorrent 0.9.8 and in Action tab of autodl irssi:

[image]

and the bash script looks very simple

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "blablabla" >> /home/test.txt
```

and then set `chmod +x rutorrent_test.sh`

Seems that command was executed

[image]

but the file `/home/test.txt` is not created

If I run bash script by hand, manually, it works fine.

Comment: Does the script run with permissions sufficient to create a file in `/home/`?

Comment: how to grant to script to create file ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is most likely an issue with the permissions.

Edit the script with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(whoami)" >> /home/test.txt
```

Then issue this command:

```
touch /home/test.txt
chmod 666 /home/test.txt
```

Now run the script again from the application, then check the file test.tmp: it will show the username this user is running from. I'm not familiar with this application in particular, so let's assume you will see `rtorrent`.

What you need to achieve next is to get the file writable for `rtorrent`. Assuming you just need to read this file, the most appropriate way is probably to have it set like this:

```
chown rtorrent:rtorrent /home/test.txt
chmod 664 /home/test.tmp
```

If this is meant to be a sort of log, I would suggest you place this file in `/var/log` rather than `/home`.